# How do I get the length(data_size / batch_size) of the tf.data.Dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to get the length of the my tf.data.Dataset. (data_size / batch_size)

In Pytorch, I could get the this by simple code:

```
length = len(data_loader)
```

But, it don't work in tensorflow 2.0.

How do I get this?

Comment: Do you want the number of elements in a batch or the size of an element or the number of elements in the whole dataset? All of them can have multiple or unknowable values so I don't think a general answer is possible. You may have to store that information yourself.

Comment: @user1318499 Oh, I see. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In TensorFlow 2.0 you create a `tf.data.Dataset` object, that is a Python iterable object.

You don't know in advance how many elements you have inside your dataset until you loop trough them all.

So, by supposing you created a dataset in this way:

```py
batch_size = 12
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(something).batch(batch_size)
```

You can have the total number of batches in this way:

```
number_of_batches = len([_ for _ in iter(dataset)])
```